# Google Cloud 2 firestore databases and cloud functions, avoiding duplicate code

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

For my company am I researching the possiblity to place the data in regions based on specific conditions to decrease latency, since this is possible since a few weeks.

The problem I faced is with using the onCall cloud function and avoiding duplicate code. When creating a function you have to specify its region, with second generation you can simply specify multiple regions like this: `region: ["first", "second"]` so that it great.
But based on that region I need it to connect to a different database, for example the first database needs to use the (default) database and the second region the us-version. I can simply use an environment variable to detect this, but I would like to keep it within the code to avoid a second step in the console.

Furthermore when using the Firestore onWrite functions(or other equivilant) you have to specify the database it triggers by, otherwise it will use the (default) database as standard. Do I have to duplicate my code and do it for each database? I could make a function of the body and then specify it within each onWrite to improve it, but still this feels like the wrong think to do.

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that there is an environment variable that gives you the name of the cloud function. Because every cloud function start with the region name, this can be used to get the location of the cloud function and therefor apply logic to use the correct database. This solves the problem for the onCall function as follows:

```js
const callCreate = onCall(
  {
    region: [constants.regions.default.functions, constants.regions.us.functions],
  }, async (request) => {
    const database = getFirestoreInstance();
```

Where the function is as follows:

```js
import constants from "../constants";
import {firestore} from "firebase-admin";

function getFirestoreInstance(): firestore.Firestore {
  const functionName = process.env.K_SERVICE || "";
  if (functionName.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("Function name not found");
  }
  const databaseURL = functionName.startsWith(constants.regions.default.functions) ?
    constants.regions.default.firestore.databaseURL :
    constants.regions.us.firestore.databaseURL;

  const database = firestore();
  database.settings({
    databaseId: databaseURL,
  });
  return database;
}

export default getFirestoreInstance;
```

Unfortunately this does not solve the problem of the trigger, because the trigger can only be on one database. So duplicate code like the following is necessary:

```js
const onCreate = onDocumentCreated(
  {
    document: constants.functions.firestore.News.location,
    region: constants.regions.default.functions,
    database: constants.regions.default.firestore.databaseURL,
    minInstances: constants.functions.firestore.News.onCreate.minInstances,
  }, async (change) => {
    if (change.data === undefined) {
      throw new Error("Change is undefined");
    }
    // Do something
  }
);

const onCreateUS = onDocumentCreated(
  {
    document: constants.functions.firestore.News.location,
    region: constants.regions.us.functions,
    database: constants.regions.us.firestore.databaseURL,
    minInstances: constants.functions.firestore.News.onCreate.minInstances,
  }, async (change) => {
    if (change.data === undefined) {
      throw new Error("Change is undefined");
    }
    // Do something
  }
);

export {onCreate, onCreateUS};
```